# .NET XMLDocument Saving Copyright Symbol Differently Than It Reads It

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument

I am reading a XML file into a .NET XMLDocument that contains the copyright symbol in the inner text of one of the elements.  Here's an example:

```
<value>© 1994-2009 All rights reserved.</value>
```

Upon inspection, the copyright character appears to have a hex value of 0xA9 and the preceding byte's value is 0xC2.  This file is encoded in ISO-8859-1.

The problem is that when I save the contents of the XMLDocument to a new file (without any modifications), the inner text is modified to the following:

```
<value>? 1994-2009 All rights reserved.</value>
```

The file output by XMLDocument.Save has a value of 0x3F (ASCII's '?' character) in place of the 0xC2 0xA9 byte sequence in the original file and is stated as having the same ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Here's a chunk of code that reproduces the problem in my unit testing environment:

```
        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmldoc.LoadXml("base.xml")
        Dim filename As String = Me.GetType().Name & "-" & TestContext.TestName & ".xfdl"
        Console.WriteLine("Saving file: " & IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir, filename))
        xmldoc.Save(filename)
```

How do I preserve the proper encoding of this node's inner text? Is this an encoding issue or is it something else?

Also, I've tried using streams to dictate the encoding such as John points out below with no success.

Answer (score -1):

See [XmlDocument.Save Method(TextWriter)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wd18z.aspx).

Create a `TextWriter` with the correct encoding, and use that instead of just passing the file name.

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument()
xmldoc.LoadXml("base.xml")
Dim filename As String = Me.GetType().Name & "-" & TestContext.TestName & ".xfdl"
Console.WriteLine("Saving file: " & IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir, filename))
Using writer As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName, correctEncoding)
    xmldoc.Save(writer)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks John! The encoding of the source file is stated as ISO-8859-1 and that matches the encoding listed on the output.  What encoding should I be using if not the encoding of the source?  As stated, simply saving to the file using the XMLDocument instance gets me the ISO-8859-1 encoding which seems preferred as it's what the original's encoding is. For grins, I've tried UTF8, UTF32, and Unicode with no success. Maybe this isn't an encoding issue at all, but it seems like one to me.